# grep a expression in an array of string with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to grep a special pattern in an array of strings.

My array of strings is like this :

```
@list=("First phrase with \"blabla - Word\" and other things "
      ,"A phrase without... "
      ,"Second phrase with \"truc - Word\" and etc... "
      ,"Another phrase without... "
      ,"Another phrase with \"thing - Word\" and etc... ");
```

and I tried to grep the pattern "..... - Word" with this function :

```
@keyw = grep { /\".* Word\"/} (@list);
```

and I have the following result :

```
print  (Dumper  (  @keyw));
$VAR1 = 'First phrase with "blabla - Word" and other things ';
$VAR2 = 'Second phrase with "truc - Word" and etc... ';
$VAR3 = 'Another phrase with "thing - Word" and etc... ';
```

My grep function is ok to grep the phrase but I would like to grep **just the pattern** and get the following result :

```
$VAR1 = '"blabla - Word"';
$VAR2 = '"truc - Word"';
$VAR3 = '"thing - Word"';
```

**Do you know how to reach this result ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `grep`:

```
my @keyw = map { /\"[^"]*? Word\"/ ? $& : () } @list;
```

It just returns `$&` (whole match) if the pattern matches and `()` (empty list) if it does not.
Little caveat: don't use `$&` with with Perl < 5.18.0.

Here's [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte)'s simpler solution:

```
my @keyw = map { /(\"[^"]*? Word\")/ } @list;
```

It works since `m//` returns a list of captured groups.

Comment: instead of using the ternary operator and `$&`, you can use a capture group. See the performance issue about using `$&`: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html . Note that the original pattern can be more waterproof if the dot is replaced (at least) with `[^"]`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte hmm... not sure I understand what you're suggesting. Returning anything short of `()` yields `undef` values in the resulting array. The performance issue of `$&` was solved long ago. You're right about `[^"]`.

Comment: I was thinking about: `my @keyw = map {/(\".* Word\")/} @list;`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte d'oh, I see, thanks :) My Perl is getting rusty.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't we just use a normal loop?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my @phrases = (
    "First phrase with \"blabla - Word\" and other things ",
    "A phrase without... ",
    "Second phrase with \"truc - Word\" and etc... ",
    "Another phrase without... ",
    "Another phrase with \"thing - Word\" and etc... ",
);

my @matches;

for (@phrases) {
    next unless /("[^"]+Word")/;
    push(@matches, $1);
}

# prints ["\"blabla - Word\"", "\"truc - Word\"", "\"thing - Word\""]
dd(\@matches);
```